# emacs autocomplete userdefined library function

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cedet

i am new to emacs ....i have installed autocomplete and configure it in my init file...but if i download a library from somewhere and has its include and lib file and want emacs to auto complete the function present in the include file of that library...what package do we install for it and how do we set emacs up to  do it...?

i have heard CEDET package in emacs would be able to do it...but how to set it up..?
If there is another package..please let me know and guide me through the whole process?

Comment: This may be interesting to you: https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice simplified introduction to installing CEDET at this url:

http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

or you can use the CEDET manual which comes with Emacs.